# Checkbox causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, checkbox

So I'm making a program using html en Javascript where the user can click a button and the program will perform a calculation and a checkbox that when checked will perform that same calculation in a loop.

```
  <body>
  <button onclick="javascript:calc();"> Calculate</button>
  <form action="">
   <input id="checkbox" type='checkbox' name='auto' value='Auto' /> 
  </form>

   <script>
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
   function calc() {
     do{
    //Calculate stuff
     }while(checkbox.checked);
    }
   </script>

   </body>
```

Problem is that when I check the checkbox the webpage just freezes because it is stuck in an infinite loop so I can't uncheck the checkbox to stop it.

Is there any way to stop it from going into an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes, there's a way, it is called [event listening](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you check the checkbox, you are putting the code into an infinite loop. That will freeze up the page and not allow the user to uncheck the box. You can try something with setTimeout like such.

```
const foo = () => {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    //do math
    setTimeout( () => {
      foo();
    }, 3000)
  }
}
```

Set the function to fire when the checkbox is clicked, and if it is checked, you can do the calculations and it will recursively call itself again after 3 seconds and check if the checkbox is still checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calc(){
if(conditionIsTrue){ // do smth here}
else{
//do another stuff here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way: not to write an infinite loop? You are performing the `// calculate stuff` part over and over (unless you have a `break` in there) while the checkbox is checked, and since it runs on the ui thread the ui is frozen.